# Controlar visibilidade de componentes da view na controller ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou refatorando um projeto em ASP.NET MVC 5, implementando algumas boas praticas e pesquisando, foi citado que o uso do if na view(razor) não é a melhor pratica, só que eu o utilizo para mostrar ou ocultar alguns componentes(campos) de acordo com a permissão do usuário atual, estou pesquisando como limitar isso pela controller para que a renderização da view seja realizada, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de fazer isso(na verdade nem sei se é possível realmente), vou colocar um exemplo de um codigo da view atual:

```
    @if ((bool)Session["TipoChamadoVisivel"])
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoChamado, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "1")<label>&nbsp;Totvs RM</label>
                <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "2")<label>&nbsp;Outros</label>
                <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    }

    @if ((bool)Session["ObraVisivel"])
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Obra Destino", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ObraDestino, new SelectList(new prj_chamadosBRA.Repositories.ObraDAO().BuscarObrasPorUsuario(ViewBag.UserId), "IDO", "Descricao"), "-- Selecione a Obra --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ObraDestino, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if ((bool)Session["SetorVisivel"])
    {
        if (Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString() != "1")
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Setor Destino", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SetorDestino, new SelectList(new prj_chamadosBRA.Repositories.SetorDAO().BuscarSetoresPorObra(ViewBag.SetorDestino), "Id", "Nome"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SetorDestino, "", new { @class = "text-danger validacaoSetor" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Setor Destino", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SetorDestino, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Nome"), "-- Selecione o Setor --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SetorDestino, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }

    @if ((bool)Session["SelecionarResponsavelAbertura"])
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#pnlResponsavelAbertura">Abrir chamado em nome de outro usuário?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="pnlResponsavelAbertura" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString() != "1" && Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString() != "4")
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Selecione Usuario:", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResponsavelAberturaChamado, new SelectList(new prj_chamadosBRA.Repositories.ApplicationUserDAO().retornarUsuariosObra(ViewBag.SetorDestino), "Id", "Nome"), "-- Selecione o usuário --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ResponsavelAberturaChamado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Selecione Usuario:", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResponsavelAberturaChamado, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Nome"), "-- Selecione a obra primeiro --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ResponsavelAberturaChamado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controle de visualização são de responsabilidade da view mesmo. O controller possui outra responsabilidade dentro do MVC, que é receber, interpretar e direcionar as requisições do usuário respondendo e acionando os controladores de cada tipo de operação.

Não há nada de errado em usar os IF's do razor dentro da view, se você criar um projeto do zero com o template de login da própria microsoft vai ver que eles utilizam de ifs para mostrar o **login** ou **logout** no canto superior de acordo com o status do model.

Realmente eu acho que o perigo aqui é você acessar e fazer uso direto da sua sessão para fazer essas validações.

Talvez fosse melhor dentro do seu **Model** você ter uma **struct** de visualizações e ai sim fazer uso dela na view.

E ai sim no seu controller você faz a manipulação de quais tipos de visualizações esse model tem e ai sim manipular a visualização na view.

Outra dica é fazer uso da **ViewData** que é exatamente um tipo de dado transitório que dura apenas entre uma requisição e a renderização da view.

Se você quer melhorar o código e deixa-lo mais limpo pode aplicar isso juntamente com o padrão de renderização parcial **Partials**

E juntando os dois poderia ficar assim

```
@if((bool)ViewData["MostrarSecao1"]) { @{Html.RenderPartial("secao1", Model);} }
@if((bool)ViewData["MostrarSecao2")) { @{Html.RenderPartial("secao2", Model);} }
```

Esses ViewData são preenchidos no seu controller.

```
ViewData["MostrarSecao1"] = //condição para mostrar a seção 1;
ViewData["MostrarSecao2"] = //condição para mostrar a seção 2;
```

E suas partials podem ficar em qualquer local do projeto (dentro de views claro) e nelas pode ter apenas seu código sem os ifs. Por exemplo

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Obra Destino", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ObraDestino, new SelectList(new prj_chamadosBRA.Repositories.ObraDAO().BuscarObrasPorUsuario(ViewBag.UserId), "IDO", "Descricao"), "-- Selecione a Obra --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ObraDestino, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Esse seu código ficaria dentro da partial **secao1.cshtml**

Answer (score 4):

Usar variáveis de sessão desta forma é bastante perigoso:

```
@if ((bool)Session["TipoChamadoVisivel"]) { ... }
```

Até porque você não testa a existência desse conteúdo antes de usá-lo.

Além disso, essa maneira de usar causa alguma poluição visual. A melhor maneira de resolver é encapsular o conteúdo através de *Partials*, testando antes se a variável de sessão existe. Por exemplo, este fragmento de código:

```
@if ((bool)Session["TipoChamadoVisivel"])
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoChamado, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "1")<label>&nbsp;Totvs RM</label>
            <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "2")<label>&nbsp;Outros</label>
            <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</p>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Pode ser encapsulado dentro de uma *Partial* chamada assim:

```
@Html.Partial("_TipoChamado", Model).If(Session["TipoChamadoVisivel"] != null)
```

Este `If` é uma extensão que pode ser implementada da seguinte forma:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Método de extensão para avaliar condições na View.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="valor"></param>
    /// <param name="avaliacao"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IHtmlString If(this IHtmlString valor, bool avaliacao)
    {
        return avaliacao ? valor : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

}
```

Outra dica é registrar o *Namespace* das extensões no `web.config` do diretório *Views*:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <!--pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage"-->
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="MeuProjeto" />
        <add namespace="MeuProjeto.Extensions" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  ...
</configuration>
```

A *Partial* ficaria assim:

```
@if ((bool)Session["TipoChamadoVisivel"]) // Agora você sabe que a variável existe, e pode usar sem problemas.
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoChamado, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "1")<label>&nbsp;Totvs RM</label>
            <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "2")<label>&nbsp;Outros</label>
            <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoChamado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</p>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```